# C# Debug and release mode

Tags: c#

How to find whether it is in debug mode or release mode? Are there any other ways to find it?

```
    #if(DEBUG)
{
       Console.WriteLine("Debug mode");
       //Or Things to do in debug mode
}
    #else
{
       Console.WriteLine("Release mode");
       //Or Things to do in Release mode- May be to change the text, image 
}
#endif
```

Comment: That's the usual way, what other way did you have in mind?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/what-s-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute.aspx

Answer (score 6):

No that's the only way, but you need to have the syntax and capitalization correct. You can also check whether the debugger is attached. Here is the correct syntax:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.Writeline("debug");
#else
    Console.Writeline("release");
#endif
    // You can also check if a debugger is attached, which can happen in either debug or release
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        Console.WriteLine("debugger attached");
```

Comment: @Kevin DiTraglia  Other way is: For debug mode we can use [Conditional("DEBUG")].

Comment: As you said, that's the only way: For debug mode can we not use [Conditional("DEBUG")]?

Comment: @Rashmi Eric Lippert has already commented on ConditionalAttributes. Did you read his link and blog? Your question isn't very clear on what you are trying to accomplish... Is there a reason that the method you showed isn't enough for you? Questions should focus on an actual problem you faced, what problem is it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using System.Diagnostics:

`if (Debugger.IsAttached) {...` ?

Comment: This checks if a debugger is attached, which can happen in either debug mode or release mode